# Code looking for modules in the wrong place

Tags: module, dojo, amd

I have created a multi-layer build using build.dojotoolkit.org (my first attempt) with 3 layers: dojo.js, dojox.js, dijit.js. Each js file is uploaded in its own folder (dojo,dojox,dijit).

When I run the code, I would expect it to look in dijit.js to get the form modules like dijit.form.TextBox. But instead it tries to load dijit/form/TextBox.js and of course ends up with a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?

The files are here if it helps: 
http://usermanagedsolutions.com/Demos/Pages

Answer (score 1):

Manually include each layer in a script tag on the page.

```
<script src="path/to/dojo.js" />
<script src="path/to/dojox.js" />
<script src="path/to/dijit.js" />
```

This will make available all modules that you have defined in the build.  When you require the text box, Dojo will see that it has the code and will not make the XHR call.

Even though you do not have the intention of using the individual files, you may want to put them on the server as well.  This way if someone forgets to add the file to the build, the penalty incurred is an xhr request, as opposed to a javascript error.

---

Re: AMD

When you include your layers in the manner that I described above, you are not loading all the modules that you included the build - you are just making the define functions available without having to make xhr requests.

If you look at the js file that is output from the build, the file contains a map of the module path to a function that when called will define the module.

So when you write the following code

```
require(["dijit/form/TextBox"], function(TextBox){
  ...
});
```

AMD will first determine if `dijit/form/TextBox` has already been defined.  If so it will just take the object and execute the callback.

If the module hasn't already been defined, then AMD will look in it's cache to see if the define code is available.  When you include your script files, you are providing a cache of define functions.  AMD finds the code to define the module.  It calls this define function and the result is the object that is passed into the callback.  Subsequent requires for `dijit/form/TextBox` will also use this object as described above.

If the module hasn't already been defined and AMD does not find the define function in its cache, then AMD will make an XHR request back to the server to try to locate the specific module code.  The result of the XHR call should provide the define function.  AMD will call the function and use the result as the object to pass into the callback.  Again, subsequent requires for `dijit/form/TextBox` will also use this object.

The Dojo build, provides the ability to 1) minify the code and 2) combine it into fewer files that need to be requested from the server.

AMD allows you to write code that can run in either environment (using built files or the individual files) without having to make modifications.

Comment: I must be missing something. What is the point of AMD if I need to load my scripts up-front? My page has two modes (form or chart), my assumption was that dojo would load dijit.js when I require a dijit module.

Comment: Enhanced my answer to address your question

Comment: Thanks Graig, this is very helpful. If I understand correctly, it means that for further optimization I need an additional layer before require that will only load the js packages I need for my specific mode. Also the suggestion to put the individual files on the server as safety net is a nice touch.

Comment: well, I tried that and I am still facing the same issue. The 3 js files load fine, but the code is still trying to load the modules from dijit/form.