# Does require used in a module add to dependencies in dojo build?

Tags: dojo

I've learned that dojo's loader can load non-amd scripts, which is awesome.  We have a script provided by a vendor that requires certain global variables to be set before the script can be loaded.   If, in my AMD module, I set the global variables (I know, yuck, right?) and then require(["/vendor/script.js"]), everything works great.

The one thing I'm having trouble finding an answer to is if the build process will see this require call and add "/vendor/script.js" to the dependency list and build it.  Which, if I understand correctly, will cause the script to fire before my module has had an opportunity to set the required global variables.

Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior is that the build will traverse the dependencies and include them in the build.  However you have options:

1) in the profile, you can specify excludes.  These will not be included into the build.

```
// profile.js used by the build

layers: {
    "myApp/myApp": {
        include:    [...],
        exclude:    [vendor/script.js]
}
```

2) do not include the dependency in the define statement and use require later in the module.  `dojo/fx` does this with `dojo/fx/toggler`

```
// myCustomWidget.js

define([], function() {
    // the require function won't be called by the build
    // and the vendorScript won't be pulled into the build.
    require(["vendor/script"], function(vendorScript) {

    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, your second example was the scenario I was asking about.   The build won't pick, up the require() in that pattern?

Comment: Right.  Take a look at the AMD part of my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806747/code-looking-for-modules-in-the-wrong-place/13808295#13808295  It describes when that function that has the require will be called.

Comment: My only other comment was that "require('vendor/script')" wouldn't work for me, but "require(['vendor/script'])" did.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create another script to set your globals, and then include that *before* including your compiled .js file.

If the values you set the globals to require modules, though, I guess you could edit the compiled .JS file after it's been built.